# Steam: how to get the package name from a package-id?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steam-protobufs

The problem is rather simple: "Steam" (that is, the gaming DRM platform), has "apps" and "packages"; the latter are pretty much licenses that are stored in your account and grant the apps (aka games) that you own.

If you look at the [license overview](https://store.steampowered.com/account/licenses/) (this only works if you have a Steam account logged in, of course -- but if you don't, why are you even reading this question)  -- the names shown there are NOT technically the name of the games you have, it's the names of the packages. This is why you might see names like "Space Crew: Legendary Edition Limited Free Promotional Package - Mar 2024" in this list.

I have no problems getting game names from app-ids and connecting games (apps) and packages (licenses).

SteamDB can also show package names, for everything. And they are not related to Valve, so they don't have access to internal databases or anything like that either.

Now, I've been trying to obtain these package names programmatically, given a `package-id` (or right now, anything -- if I can get package-names in any way, shape or form I can probably find a way to connect them to their `package-id`). SteamDB also calls them `sub-id` but that's the same thing.

I have a working client application aka bot aka whatever you want to call it, so I don't even care whether it's a protobuf message sent through the client connection, an authenticated web query (i.e. http(s) query or webpage requiring a login), or a public web query that just anyone can use. I have support for everything in the code.

As protobufs go, there is the `CMsgClientPICSProductInfoRequest` which lets me query information about a `package_id` -- the response has various information about the package, but no name. Yes, I also added a `meta_data_only=false` just in case that's not the default.

I also found [the StorefrontAPI](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI) -- which has a query for `packagedetails` with a `packageids` parameter, which looks great. It even does what I expect -- but only for a select few packages. Every hint I see on this API also states that it's unofficial, and since it doesn't provide information for the vast majority of packages, it's obviously not the API that SteamDB uses (they have information on EVERY package, apparently).

I also found a `CMsgClientPackageInfoRequest` protobuf message, which has a response with an unspecified `buffer` (this happens occasionally; that buffer tends to be key-value with various items, but I don't currently know what it actually contained). Unfortunately, when I look for the message id so I can actually send it, I find 833 -- which SteamKit doesn't have, except in a file where it's marked as "removed". Still, I tried sending it anyway, and got no response... I can't know whether I was using correctly, but finding the ID as "removed" kind of makes me think that's not the problem.

I was also grepping through SteamKit and the proto files for various keywords and looking at things that popped up, but nothing.

And, of course, Google is generally unhelpful for this.

Answer (score 1):

For packageids you have a license for, it seems lik get/pair package IDs and package names by parsing the HTML of some support pages which are intended for removing and restoring licenses:
https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithGameIssue/?appid=RELEVANT_APP_ID&issueid=123
https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithGameIssue/?appid=RELEVANT_APP_ID&issueid=101
https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpPackageRestored?appid=RELEVANT_APP_ID&packageid=PACKAGE_ID

Visiting the HelpPackageRestored page does restore the license without any further interaction, so you'll want to keep that in mind.
Some packageids only work with one page or the other. But even between them, I'm not sure if all packageids work. I'm still looking into this.

It [seems](https://bbs.ruliweb.com/best/board/300007/read/1926550) that in the past, a Steam support page could be used to look up any packageid's name. But this was used to find names of unannounced packagesids, which is probably why this functionality is no longer available.

Comment: From previous edit: "Edit by @Christian Stieber: well, this deleted answer does at least point into a direction I've never looked at (since I've never used these support pages, so I didn't even know what they look like...). I guess I don't want to try that second link, but I might eventually get around to try the first one just to see whether it gives me a useful number of package names, and/or maybe get idea what packages it does or does not give info on."

Comment: @Christian Stieber Sorry, I deleted it as it was bit incomplete, but I probably shouldn't have done that. Glad you found it useful. I'll continue updating it with any further findings.

Comment: I'm still "only" putting it on my list of things to try, but given the absence of any actual "yeah, there's a simple API for that..." replies, this might actually be the accepted answer, if I can get more than just a few package names.

I might not have mentioned it in my question, and I always prefer general APIs -- I don't think SteamDB owns all those licenses that they have names for -- but right now, I only need package names for stuff that the account making the query actually owns, so it's not such a big deal other than designing the internal API appropriately...

Comment: Yeah its not ideal, but I don't know if there's a proper API for it. I think SteamDB got most package names using that former method I mentioned. And for newer ones, by crowdsourcing them through the methods listed [here](https://steamdb.info/faq/#package-token). But they don't provide any method to access the crowdsourced data except the HTML on their bot-protected site, so I'm not sure that's of any use.

Comment: no, unless they specifically allow people to use their website like that, I don't want to use SteamDB for anything other than research purposes. regardless of whether I can defeat the bot-protection or not :-) Heck, I don't really like accessing the user-facing Steam website either, but since I'm not downloading anything referenced on the page, the associated headache is rather minor and my webpage-code has several levels of rate-limiting... and this would be another API that shares the data across all accounts and caches it as well.